# use tow locale in php faker at same time

Tags: php, faker

im using laravel 7 and im using php faker .. 
if i want to seed customer i did this code ..

```
$factory->define(App\Models\Customer::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'number' => $faker->numberBetween(1,1000000),
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'foreign_name' => $faker->name,
        'financial_account_type_id' => 2,
        'address' => $faker->address,
        'tax_id' => $faker->numberBetween(1,100000),
        'phone' => $faker->e164PhoneNumber,
        'mobile' => $faker->e164PhoneNumber,
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'sales_payment_term_id' => $faker->numberBetween(1,7),
        'purchase_payment_term_id' => $faker->numberBetween(1,7),
        'note' => $faker->sentence,
    ];
});
```

now in my app.php i did this code also ..

```
'faker_locale' => 'ar_SA',
```

i want the `'foreign_name' => $faker->name,` to be in english language just this line .. 
is that possible to change only one line locale .. 
thanks ..

Comment: Well I guess you could just create an additional `Faker` instance that uses a different locale, and then just use `'name' => $additionalFaker->name` …?

Comment: could you wright the code please

Comment: This is not a code-writing service, you need to make your own attempt first. We can try and help you if you can not get it working, but that requires that you show what exactly you tried, and give us a proper problem description along with it.